# Почему я не могу редактировать свои комментарии?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка

*Почему* сразу в двух смыслах.

1. Я не до конца понял, после какого действия я уже не могу отредактировать свой же комментарий. Либо после определённого количества правок, либо после того, как на него кто-то ответил.
2. Зачем существует подобный запрет?

Comment: 1) imho 5 минут прошло. 2) тут (на этом сайте) много непонятных ограничений.

Comment: @avp, ага. долго не мог понять, почему не получается задать вопрос(нет конкретизации что именно не так). оказалось мало текста. Вставил хвостом бессмысленного текста, потом удалил после отправки запроса, прокатило:)

Comment: @pegoopik о проблеме с недостаточным количеством бессмысленного текста в вопросе: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3369/181472 =)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Запрет на редактирование комментариев после определённого времени (на текущий момент — 5 минут) сделан для того, чтобы не терялся контекст беседы. Представьте себе: я написал комментарий, вы ответили на него, я поменял текст комментария задним числом на прямо противоположный, теперь ответы на него выглядят глупо.

Поскольку об изменении в комментариях не приходят нотификации (иначе их было бы *слишком* много), у вас не будет возможности узнать, что мой текст изменился, и соответственно поправить ваш комментарий. Поэтому комментарии и замораживаются, решая тем самым проблему.

Comment: У комментариев тоже есть период свежести )

Comment: Комментарий можно удалить, и этим часто пользуются, поэтому контекст все-равно может теряться. Тогда нужно запрещать удаление после 5 минут.

Comment: @cheops: Это не ко мне, это feature request на en.Meta.

Comment: @cheops комментарии нередко устаревают, так что удаление уместно.

Comment: Иногда комментариев очень много и часто не несут информации, поэтому их стоит удалять

Comment: Кстати, нотификаций об изменении вопроса/ответа тоже нет. Только первый автор сообщения уведомляется, если кто-то его сообщение поправит.